# How to improve the performance of [NSString drawInRect:withFont]?

Tags: iphone, performance, uitableview, scroll, drawrect

I'm implementing an app for a micro blog service, something similar to twitter. I've done everything I know to improve the performance, including using `drawRect` instead of sub view based architecture.

After run the app with Instrument, I found that `[NSString drawInRect:withFont]` takes up more than 50% time, especially during the first time scrolling, after which I can scroll quite smoothly. Although `[NSString drawInRect:withFont]` still takes up the most of time, it's significantly smoother, and no obvious lag can be noticed.

I don't know if the layers are cached or something, but with break point and NSLog I can see that `drawRect` and `drawInRect` are still called. Then why it only lags at the first time of scrolling?

The twitter's official app really has excellent performance. Is there any insider that can tell me some practical tricks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Loren Bricher, the developer behind the Twitter app wrote a blog post about just this.

You can check it out here: http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview

(Tweetie is the name of the official Twitter app before it was bought by Twitter, in case you didn't know.)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Actually that's the one I'm copying from. It's really a useful article. I do have improved the performance a lot. However, as I mentioned above, the first time scrolling still lags a bit while there's no lag during the second time and later on. I noticed the performance difference between drawAtPoint and drawInRect. Since the demo from atebits only shows one line of text, I don't know how the guy deals with paragraph to get that performance.